# Check if a match date is between two dates of the tournement

Tags: mysql

i've 2 different tables in my DB, tournement with start_date and end_date; the table match it's like (pid, date, tid) with tid as a Foreign key from tournement. I'd like to check when i'll add something in match table that date is between start and end dates of the torunement.
something like this but it doesn't work:

````
add constraint chkdates check(
    start_d=(SELECT end_date FROM tournement as T,match as P where p.tid=t.tid);
    end_d=(SELECT data_inizio FROM tournement as T,match as P where p.tid=t.tid);
    match_date between inizio and fine);```

thanks for helping.
````

Comment: Constraint cannot. Use trigger logic.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use subqueries in [constraint expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html), sad to say.

Comment: is it possible to make with a trigger?